# "Sort by name" only sorts random groupings of files in the same folder under Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I noticed something with the latest Windows Update that I haven't noticed before that point:

I seem to have some strange glitch that when "sorting by name" it does so for a seemingly random number of files, then starts a whole other grouping of alphabetically sorted files underneath.

For example, this is a listing of one folder I have when sorting by name in ascending order in Windows Explorer:

```
SGM Solo Vox.fst

SGM Whistle.fst

SGM Choir Aahs.fst

SGM Halo Pad.fst

SGM Space Voice.fst

SGM Synth Vox.fst

SGM Voice Oohs.fst
```

"Solo Vox" and "Whistle" are in the wrong place. It's like this with many other of my files, with varying amounts per "grouping" in the same folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Do you maybe have the `Group By` setting enabled? It's next to `Sort By` in the View menu of Windows Explorer. If you are grouping by something that Solo Vox and Whistle have in common, but the other files do not, that could explain the order you are seeing.

Comment: You might be sorting by more than one column, with something other than Name being higher on the list. Under View, Sort By, look for "Choose Columns". Make sure that Name is at the top of the list if you want that as your primary sort criterion.

Comment: I tried everything you said and none of it fixed the situation, unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the Windows Explorer display? That might help someone recognize something.

Comment: http://oi63.tinypic.com/2cmviqa.jpg
Interesting thing about the above: I created a brand new file called "SGM Solo Vox.fst" and it still results in the same issue. Same situation with moving the file to a different folder. 

http://oi68.tinypic.com/11rxd6u.jpg <- Another folder with the same problem. @DougDeden

Comment: Another update, it seems like if I get rid of the prefix "SGM" (or "CT") in the filenames, the files sort as they should, but adding the prefix back to the filename results in wrong ordering again. Maybe Windows has some strange character limit or glitch with sorting?